# React htmlFor: I corrected the erros in code, but the warnings still appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was getting the warning:
`Warning: Invalid DOM property 'for'. Did you mean 'htmlFor'?`

I already changed to `'htmlFor'` every where I used `'for'`. But the warnings didn't go away.

I used VS Code to search through all files for '`for=`' and all results where '`htmlFor=`'. So I believe everything is correct but the warning still appears.

Comment: try stopping the react script and re-running it

Comment: @innocent already did that, and it didn't fix

Comment: can you add code to show what changes you have made?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some context: the complete error message you are getting, where the error message is emanating from (browser console? lint error in editor? build script?), and the salient code (if possible and practical).  These details would make it easier for the community to provide feedback specific to your situation.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you haven't rebuilt the code?
Did you run e.g. `npm run build` after the change?